# Generate each column of the numpy array with random number from different range

Tags: python, numpy

How to generate a numpy array such that each column of the array comes from a uniform distribution within different ranges efficiently? The following code uses two for loop which is slow, is there any matrix-style way to generate such array faster? Thanks.

```
import numpy as np
num = 5
ranges = [[0,1],[4,5]]
a = np.zeros((num, len(ranges)))
for i in range(num):
    for j in range(len(ranges)):
        a[i, j] = np.random.uniform(ranges[j][0], ranges[j][1])
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What you can do is produce all random numbers in the interval [0, 1) first and then scale and shift them accordingly:

```
import numpy as np
num = 5
ranges = np.asarray([[0,1],[4,5]])
starts = ranges[:, 0]
widths = ranges[:, 1]-ranges[:, 0]
a = starts + widths*np.random.random(size=(num, widths.shape[0]))
```

So basically, you create an array of the right size via `np.random.random(size=(num, widths.shape[0]))` with random number between 0 and 1. Then you scale each value by a factor corresponding to the width of the interval that you actually want to sample. Finally, you shift them by `starts` to account for the different starting values of the intervals.

Comment: Excellent method!

Answer (score 8):

[`numpy.random.uniform`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.uniform.html) will broadcast its arguments, it can generate the desired samples by passing the following arguments:

- `low`: the sequence of low values.
- `high`: the sequence of high values.
- `size`: a tuple like `(num, m)`, where `m` is the number of ranges and `num` the number of groups of `m` samples to generate.

For example:

```
In [23]: num = 5

In [24]: ranges = np.array([[0, 1], [4, 5], [10, 15]])

In [25]: np.random.uniform(low=ranges[:, 0], high=ranges[:, 1], size=(num, ranges.shape[0]))
Out[25]: 
array([[  0.98752526,   4.70946614,  10.35525699],
       [  0.86137374,   4.22046152,  12.28458447],
       [  0.92446543,   4.52859103,  11.30326391],
       [  0.0535877 ,   4.8597036 ,  14.50266784],
       [  0.55854656,   4.86820001,  14.84934564]])
```